# How do you create a node.js style Readable Stream in a browser using native JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-stream

You can *read* a Readable Stream that is produced by a browserified lib. You can also create a Readable Stream using a lib like `highland.js`.

Is there then a way to create Node.js style Readable Streams in a browser that doesnt rely on an external lib?

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment, although there is a [Streams standard](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/) currently in the works that you may want to follow.

Comment: Will do. Glad that there are other people who have the same needs